# Mule: Triggering a process API that calls a System API

Tags: mule

I have built a process API (which is a POST) that calls another system API to retrieve some information , question I have is how can I trigger the process API for testing purpose? Also if I were to add a poller , how would the poller invoke this process API?

```
     <flow name="postData" processingStrategy="synchronous">

    <http:request config-ref="call-system-api" path="/getInfo" method="GET" doc:name="call backend">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:query-param paramName="modifiedAfter" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.get(&quot;modifiedAfter&quot;)]"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HTTP Request, 
You could postman, to post request.
If you are going to add a poller, you would place the poller as the first component of the flow.
 Here is an example.

```
<poll doc:name="Poll">
   <http:request config-ref="" path="" method="" doc:name="HTTP"/>
 </poll>
```